# Why is the paintComponent() method executed without being called?

Tags: java, class, methods, overriding

i am just learning Java , today i ran into a problem while practicing. first, I inherited from **JPanel** and drew a diagonal line using the paintComponent method. but in the main class of the program, I never called the paintComponent method, but still it was executed. How is such a thing possible?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        g.drawLine(0 , 0 , w , h);
     }
}
```

then i added MyPanel to JFrame in the main class :

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class main26 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyPanel p1 = new MyPanel();
        JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
        f1.add(p1);
        f1.setSize(500,500);
        f1.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f1.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

In fact, i expected that the diagonal line would not be executed until I called the paintComponent method from MyPanel. But to my surprise, this line was drawn without calling it and just by adding MyPanel to JFrame .

Comment: Add a block of code in your `paintComponent` method that will throw an exception. Then catch it and inside the catch block, call the exception's `printStackTrace` method. Then you'll see how it's called.

Comment: Internally Swing components will call the paintComponent(...) method when the component needs to be painted. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for the high level overview of how painting works. Don't forget to click on the "Painting in Awt and Swing" link for more details.

Comment: The system where you’re running (Windows, OSX, Linux, etc.) will continually ask windows to paint themselves.  Java translates each such request into a call to `paint`, which in Swing components will delegate to paintComponent (and a few other methods).

Comment: See the checked answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7764602/how-is-paint-running-without-being-called-in-the-main-method

Comment: @Jeff FYI `Thread#dumpStack()` does that without needing to throw and catch an Exception

Comment: @amir check the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JComponent.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) of `paint()`: "Invoked by Swing to draw components. ...  This method actually delegates the work of painting to three protected methods: `paintComponent`, `paintBorder`, and `paintChildren`."

Comment: @user85421, poor wording on my part. My point was that behind the scenes  paintComponent() is automatically invoked whenever the component needs to be painted so you NEVER need to invoke it directly.  You should also NEVER invoke paint() directly, so I would not consider that the starting point for painting a component. As I stated in my answer read the tutorial and follow the links for a more in depth description of everything that goes on for a component to be painted.

Comment: @camickr 1) my comment was clearly meant to OP, I even added an (unnecessary) @; 2) I never said it is the starting point of anything, it is just an explanation of "Why is the paintComponent() method executed" - the title of this question; 3) it also explains that, I quote: "Applications should not invoke paint directly, ..." (I will not repeat the whole documentation here, you are actually one that already disapproved such before)